# How to insert some data into an array of index of a class with for loop and how to view them?

Tags: java, arrays

How to insert data into an array with loop? suppose i have a class Teacher with empty constructor Teacher() data with name, id etc. How to insert name on that teacher class with for loop from the main class?

I have tried entering data with loop but at the time of view the data shows me array index out of bounds.

```java
Teacher [] a = new Teacher[2];
for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Number "+i+" Teacher name: ");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    a[i] = new Teacher(name, "ECE", "141", "SIA", 2345678);
}
System.out.println(a[a.length - 1].toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(a[i].getName());
}
```

**Updated** tried the better answer but same problem occurs. Guys my problem is on the time of inserting data into the array at line 
**a[i] = new Teacher(name, "ECE", "141", "SIA", 2345678);** here the exception occurs. like the data couldn't get inserted.

```java
Number 0 Teacher name: 
siat
Number 1 Teacher name: 
manik
Number 2 Teacher name: 
munna
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at oop.SchoolMain.main(SchoolMain.java:31)
```

Comment: You have created an array of length 2 (`Teacher[] a = new Teacher[2];`), but you are trying to access a third element by `a[2].toString()`. Indexes start at `0`, which means there are the indexes `0` and `1` in an array of two elements.

Comment: It will crash before that, his first loop will loop 3 times, so he'll get the exception at the third assignment of `a[i] = new Teacher(...)`.

Comment: I don't understand why you are not understanding the answers! Your output asks for filling in 3 teacher details, but you have only 2 locations in the array. Fixing the loop evaluation condition is the fix.

Comment: You need to see the answers ... many people have suggested to change `<=` to `<` in first `for-loop` yet you are making same mistake

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, i get it now and fixed it. i didn't notice about the <= at the first time now i got it done.
on the first loop the <= operator was messing things up. 
thanks for the help.
and sorry for doing this type of silly mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared your array to have `2` elements:

```
Teacher [] a = new Teacher[2];
```

They are placed at indexes `0` and `1`.

In the following loop you iterate from `0` to `2` so you try to access the element at index `2`. There's no such an element, as explained above.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
}
```

The same happens in this line. Index `2` again.

```
System.out.println(a[2].toString());
```

I assume you want to access the last element so you could do it like this:

```
System.out.println(a[a.length - 1].toString());
```

Your first loop should look like the second, where you iterate up to `a.length` so you won't access element at index greater than the last index in the array.

This is how the code should look like:

```
Teacher [] a = new Teacher[2];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i+">Name: ");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    a[i] = new Teacher(name, "123", "ECE", "sia", 234567);
}
System.out.println(a[a.length -1].toString());
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(a[i].getName());
}
```

Comment: thank you 
did it like this but the data couldn't get inserted on the a[i] index
see the updated question

Comment: You still have `<=` instead of `<` comparison operator. That's the cause of exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have created an array of length `2`, so the possible indexes on that array are 0 & 1 only.

Now you have looped `i = 0 to i <= 2`, at a point it will try to access the array like below :

```
 a[2] = new Teacher(name, "123", "ECE", "sia", 234567);
```

Which is not valid as `2` is not a valid index for that array and you will get an array out of bound exception.

Comment: well i get the fact about index but the problem is at the time of inserting data. 


```java
Teacher [] a = new Teacher[2];
for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
 System.out.println("Number "+i+" Teacher name: ");
 String name = in.nextLine();
 a[i] = new Teacher(name, "ECE", "141", "SIA", 2345678);
}
System.out.println(a[a.length - 1].toString());
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
 System.out.println(a[i].getName());
}
```
my target is to fill up the index with loop 
just like we fill the array of index like this

Comment: "my target is to fill up the index with loop just like we fill the array of index like this " what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: well, I'm not being able to make things straight. 
but i finally got it right. it was <= operator which was causing the exception. 
sorry man for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Array Index out of bound error occurs when you are trying to access an array element from an index which is not a valid index.
In this case, you have allocated the array such that it can take up two Teacher objects. So the valid indices are 0 and 1.

> Teacher [] a = new Teacher[2];

And while looping you are trying to access three Teachers(0,1,2). But unfortunately, you have allocated only two teachers and hence this error.

> for (int i = 0; i ***<=*** 2; i++) {
>   }

To solve this issue, you can get the length of the array using (a.length)
So all the loops should be modified as:

> for (int i = 0; i ***<*** a.length; i++) {
>   }

In addition, in the below line you are trying to access from index 2 (again not a valid index).

> System.out.println(a[***2***].toString());

So, this line should also be changed.

To summarise,
You can access elements only from valid indices. For an array of size n, the valid indices are 0 to n-1.

The modified code that will work will be -

```
    Teacher [] a = new Teacher[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(i+">Name: ");
      String name = in.nextLine();
      a[i] = new Teacher(name, "123", "ECE", "sia", 234567);
    }
    System.out.println(a[a.length-1].toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(a[i].getName());
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: same problem at the time of inserting on a[i]

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: While I definitely agree that allocating extra resources isn't a good practice, it is something I recommend if one is a beginner programmer.

As everyone here is pointing out about your array length. I suggest you make your array size more than you need since an array's size can't be changed after declaration.

Instead of

```java
Teacher [] a = new Teacher[2];
```

```java
//A bigger array so you won't run into exception issues.
Teacher[] a = new Teacher[6];
```

MrJoe's answer definitely solves your issue, so give his answer a read!

Comment: Well thanks for the reply, there was a problem on my code i get it now. 
what i really want to do is i will insert data on those indexes' with loop. on each loop i will insert data and the array will be fill up. 
but in my case loop is okay but when i insert data on the array that time things get messed up. well my target is to fill up data of the array of indexs' with loop

Comment: @abhvemp Never allocate extra resources, if you don't want them.

Comment: @kris I agree. We all learn about memory and efficiency. However, MD Nasirul Islam did not mention that he needed only two values upon input (besides his declaration, where he set the length to two). So I thought he was confused with array declaration and I put and suggested to increase size.